# Are there generic smart pointers?

Tags: c++, generics, smart-pointers

I recently read about the various smart pointer types and i think that especially unique_ptr will be extremely useful, and shared_ptr with weak_ptr as well to some extent. However i'm not sure how to create "generic" functions which can deal with either pointer type and if that would even be a good idea.

So imagine having a vector of objects encapsulated by a smart pointer an you would like to apply some action to all elements using a function, something like this:

```
void doSomething(vector<shared_ptr<SomeType>>& array) {
   // iterate over all array elements and do something
}
```

Obviously you will need to replicate this function three times for shared/unique/weak_ptr, which is somewhat cumbersome. It would be easier to have a "generic"/"polymorphic" smart pointer type which fits all of them for function parameter usage:

```
void doSomething(vector<generic_ptr<SomeType>>& array) {
   // iterate over all array elements and do something
   // no matter if array is a vector<shared_ptr> or vector<unique_ptr>
}
```

So, does there exist such a smart pointer? If yes - which problems may arise from its usage? If no - why not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Differt pointer types allow different ownership handling with different runtime overhead required. In your case you can use template:

```
template<typename TVector>
void doSomething(TVector& array) {
   // iterate over all array elements and do something
}
```

And use common for all of smart(and not so smart) pointers `operator*` and `operator->`

Comment: I wonder if something like `template<typename generic_ptr> void doSomething(vector<generic_ptr<SomeType>>& array)` would work.

Comment: @Dukeling template<template<class> class  generic_ptr, class SomeType> void doSomething(vector<generic_ptr<SomeType>>& array) may do the trick, thru I don't see in what way it can be useful.

Comment: @Dukeling: That's just silly. What if the container changes to a `deque`? What if a user has a vector with a non-standard allocator? It's much more natural to template on the entire container type.

Comment: You might want to call the template parameter `RangeOfPointersToSomeType` or similar, to indicate to the reader that the `doSomething` function is going to dereference an element and expect to find a `SomeType` on the end of it.

Comment: @KerrekSB Then you may be able to template the container in the same way, but I do see the potential problems (not that changing 2 lines if a problem were to arise from future changes is a big deal). Though it makes sense to me from a safe coding point of view - it's less likely that you'll pass incorrect types to the function, which may either throw a possibly cryptic error or actually compile under certain circumstances. But Steve's suggestion of naming the parameter better may be more practical.

Answer (score 4):

Some misconceptions lead to an awkward code style:

1. Smart pointers are as generic as raw pointers: you can treat them much the same when calling functions of the pointed-to objects. If you really need to pass them to functions taking a raw pointer (and those functions will not take ownership), you can use their `get()` function to give you that pointer. See 3.
2. Functions acting on collections should not take the collection as a parameter, but instead be a template taking a pair of iterators, which can then be used by dereferencing the pointers pointed to by the iterators, giving you a reference to the real object.
3. Don't write functions taking raw pointers. Use references instead and dereference at the call site. I'm aware this isn't always possible, but most often it is.

An alternative to looping in a function, is making the function act on a single object (reference), and putting the loop at the call-site. C++11 makes this very clean:

```
void some_function(item_type& item); // const if necessary
for(auto&& item_ptr : collection_of_item_smart_ptrs)
  some_function(*item_ptr);
```

Clearly formulating intent, purpose, and type without any syntactical or stylistic hassle.

Answer (score 0):

All of these pointer types actaully wrap a bare pointer. So we have two cases:

1. Your method modifies the pointer in some way. In this case you will not be able to generalize it as it should different cases depending on the type.
2. You never modify the pointer. Simply pass const bare pointer to the function.

Answer (score 0):

Each of these smart pointer types has its onw usage model.

- unique_ptr can not be put in a container, it is neither copyable nor copy-assignable
- weak_ptr must be converted shared_ptr in order to access the referenced object. Usable for a cache for example, cumbersome to use all over the place.
- shared_ptr is the way to go in you situation

Comment: At the point at which you have a conforming `unique_ptr` you are in C++11 world and then you can store non-copyable, non-copy-assignable types in a container provided they are movable. `unique_ptr` is movable.

Comment: @Charles Bailey: You are absolutely right. With C++11 it works just perfectly. I always wonder why people assume you mean the older standards when it comes to C(++) rather than the current version (even if not all features are yet available in all compilers)